# How to hold employee gross pay in an array

Tags: java

I have been asked to create a java program that calculate the gross pay, taxes and the net pay. I have no problem to get the right output for that. But, the project also requires me to hold each employee's gross pay until the input becomes 'quit', and display the gross pay, tax deductions and net pay for each employee. that's where my problem starts. I know that i have to use Arrays to hold each employee's gross pay, but I do NOT know how.

I really appreciate all helps!!!

Comment: To use an Array you will need to know the max amount of elements in that array.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class Employee with grossPay, tax and netPay as attributes. Store the values you calculate to objects of this class. Keep adding the Employee objects to a List until 'quit'.